# A non-cyclic quartic

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given the quartic $x^4 - 2c x^3 + (c^2 - d^2) x^2 + 2a^2 c x - a^2 c^2 = 0$ for integers $a$,$b$ and $c$ where $d^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Looking at the Galois group $G$ of this quartic, we can WLOG assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive, $a < b$ and $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$.

Assume that we have the case $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. We then know that the discriminant $D$ is a sum of two integer squares. This gives that the quartic must factorize over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$.

Using some theory from algebraic number theory, it has been shown that no odd prime dividing $D$ is totally ramified. This means that either the discriminant is  2 times a square or a square. The latter case is not possible since the quartic is irreducible.

So, the quartic must factorize over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ if $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Using this, I had hoped to show that such a factorization is also impossible, i.e. that
$G$ is never $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for our quartic.

Note the case $a = b$ has been settled  by the author such in this case, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ can never occur as $G$.

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Kent Holing,
NORWAY

Comment: Please start with a clear context,. The WLOG is hard to be understood. WLOG so that what  happens?! (Why not also take WLOG $c=0$?!) So please assume, all you consider that can be / should be assumed. Then please isolate a proposition, that may be true or false. And finally please ask one clear question, showing what you have done in the direction of an answer / of a solution. The title "a **non**-cyclic qua(r)tic" is maybe also not reflecting the fact that some Galois group should be $\Bbb Z/4$ finally.

Comment: The discriminant of the polynomial is $D = a^2b^2c^2(c^6 - 3c^4d^2 + (3d^4 - 27a^2d^2 + 27a^4)c^2 - d^6)$. Thus the last factor must be a square or twice a square.

Comment: The only thing I asume is that about a, b and c and that G=Z4. It can then be proved that the quartic factorizes over Q[Sqrt[2]]. I should like to use that to prove that this cannot happen, ruling out G = Z4.